# how to get position of row and column in table view

Tags: android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

I am a beginner in android. 
I am trying to get position of current image, the dynamic row and column,but I don't know how to do this.Below is my code,please help me:

```
MainActivity extends Activity {

    int i,j;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] row = { "ROW1", "ROW2", "Row3"};
        String[] column = { "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2","CO" };
        int rl=row.length; int cl=column.length;

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column,rl, cl);
        HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        setContentView(sv);

    }

    public void makeCellEmpty(TableLayout tableLayout, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // get row from table with rowIndex
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);

        // get cell from row with columnIndex
        TextView textView = (TextView)tableRow.getChildAt(columnIndex);

        // make it black
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public void setHeaderTitle(TableLayout tableLayout, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){

        // get row from table with rowIndex
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);

        // get cell from row with columnIndex
        TextView textView = (TextView)tableRow.getChildAt(columnIndex);

        textView.setText("Hello");
    }

    private TableLayout createTableLayout(String [] rv, String [] cv, final int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bookshelf);

        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowParams.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
        tableRowParams.weight = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

           tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bookshelf);

            for (j= 0; j < columnCount; j++) {

                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.businessman);

                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position : " + rowCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                tableRow.addView(imageView, tableRowParams);

            }

            // 6) add tableRow to tableLayout
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableLayoutParams);
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: what you got in position ? or Any other error message?

Comment: position 3 on click on every Image.so i want to actual position

Comment: Its better to use `GridView`.

Comment: how to use gridview i want data inside like bookshelf view give me solution please

Comment: set the tag and id to each image view in row dynamically and try to get the tagin imageview.onClick and its approprate data or position.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by GridView. See the below sample code.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 9;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(TestActivity.this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.emoticons_bear);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

Your layout should be;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/gridview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:columnWidth="90dp"
          android:numColumns="auto_fit"
          android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's better to use GridView for this. But in case you need TableLayout only, you can use "final" to fix your i,j values in loops:

```
final int row = i;
final int col = j;
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "row : " + row + "; col : " + col, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
});
```